# Dynamically change Stripe final cost with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am developing a website with `WooCommerce` and `Stripe`.

On the checkout page, when the user selects the state, the tax and final price are dynamically changed depending on the state. For that feature I used jQuery.

The problem that I am having is to change the value of the Stripe purchase with jQuery.

```
<div id="stripe-payment-data" data-panel-label="" data-description="" data-email="" data-amount="640" data-name="Website" data-currency="usd" data-image="" data-bitcoin="false" data-locale="en" data-allow-remember-me="false">
  <p>Pay with your credit card (powered by <a target="blank" href="https://stripe.com/">Stripe</a>).</p>
</div>
```

I am able to change the `data-amount="640"`, but when I click to pay it doesn't change. I can imagine that the final price is sent somewhere like a session or something similar.

Does anyone have any idea how I can dynamically change the price of the final checkout with Stripe?

Thank you

Comment: This documentation page explains the best practices for this. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: As stated above, if you're trying to modify the amount shown in checkout dynamically you'd need to use the 'custom' checkout integration and pass the 'amount' param rather than the simple code block with data-amount --- if that's what woo commerce uses you might need to retrofit custom checkout on top of what's there.